# Microsoft Access Invisible Calendar for Date/Time Fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I manage a group of databases connected to an Azure SQL server, accessed through Microsoft access.  There is a small group of these databases that all of a sudden will not show the calendar icon to pick a date, whereas the rest are able to do it just fine.  I compared all fields in the properties tabs of the two fields, and nothing seems to change that would explain this.  The only differences I can notice are that, in design view, the databases with a working calendar will be called a 'Date/Time' datatype, while the group that has the invisible date picker are called 'Date/Time Extended.'  I also noticed that changing the datatype from datetime2(0) back to regular datetime changes nothing.  The data types are the same on the back end, but are called different names only in the linked access table, which is uneditable.  This may be the cause of the issue, but it seems much more likely that it's an access form issue.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you changed the datatype in backend so all are the same now, relink tables.

Comment: Also make sure, that your database under Settings is _not_ set to support the extended DateTime.